# Python load .txt as array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file

Just have a colors.txt file with data:

```
[(216, 172, 185), (222, 180, 190), (231, 191, 202), (237, 197, 206), (236, 194, 204), (227, 184, 194), (230, 188, 200), (232, 192, 203), (237, 199, 210), (245, 207, 218), (245, 207, 218)]
```

now just try to read this in python as an array

```
f = open("colors.txt", "r")
data = f.read()
data2 = np.append(data)
f.close()
```

now want to print first value but I have an error

```
print(data2[0])
```

> TypeError: _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional
>   argument: 'values'

Comment: You aren't using `np.append` as specified by its docs.  Why are you using it here?  What's it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Where does that data come from? I strongly recommend using context managers to handle file objects.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are appending in string data from your file, when you really want a `list`. So use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely evaluate the data type:

```py
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

with open('colors.txt') as fh:
    data = literal_eval(fh.read())

# np.array can consume a list
arr = np.array(data)

array([[216, 172, 185],
       [222, 180, 190],
       [231, 191, 202],
       [237, 197, 206],
       [236, 194, 204],
       [227, 184, 194],
       [230, 188, 200],
       [232, 192, 203],
       [237, 199, 210],
       [245, 207, 218],
       [245, 207, 218]])
```

You also don't want to use `np.append`, since this takes two arguments, the array you are appending to and the data to append. You want to construct an array out of the data you have read from the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to evaluate the text representation back into a python type:

```
f = open("colors.txt", "r")
data = f.read()
data = eval(data)
data2 = np.append(data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

use eval method to read your text and append in empty array

```
import numpy

data1=[]
f = open("colors.txt", "r")
data = f.read()
f.close()

L = eval(data)
print(L)
data2 = numpy.append(data1,L)
print(data2[0])
```

Comment: add context/explenation to avoid bot flagging and removal. (From LQ-Posts Review).